# Does LyX support hyperlink and hypertarget commands?

Tags: hyperref, lyx

Does LyX support `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` commands, or do I have to access them through ERTs?

Is there any other way to make text links without `hyperlink`/`hypertarget` that LyX supports? I want to have a sentence that I can click on to move to another part of the document.

Answer (score 1):

**Linking document parts in LyX**

In LyX, linking between points or parts inside a document, is done via cross-references. Quoting from [The LyX User’s Guide, version 2.0.x](http://wiki.lyx.org/uploads/LyX/LyXDevelDocumentation/2.0/UserGuide.pdf), section *6. More Tools*, sub-section *6.1. Cross-References*:

> You can reference every section, float, footnote, formula, and list in
>   the document. To reference a document part, you have to insert a label
>   into it. The label is used as an anchor and a name for the reference.

First, create a label (**Insert** > **Label...** ) for the part that is to be referenced. Second, create a cross-reference (**Insert** > **Cross-Reference...**) to make a *clickable* reference which will direct to the labeled part of the document.

One can define the color of the *links* by using hyperref's options. In **Document** > **Settings** > **PDF Properties** check the **Use Hyperref Support** and then define the link-color of interest in the **Additional options** field, i.e. `linkcolor=magenta`.

**Making arbitrary text parts linkable**

Currently there is no identical implementation of [hyperref](https://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/ftp/doc/manual.html)'s `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` [additional user macros](https://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-140004) (see also [LaTeX/Hyperlinks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Hyperlink_and_Hypertarget) at wikibooks.org) in form of an inset within LyX. A thread in [lyx-devel](http://www.lyx.org/MailingLists#toc3)'s mailing list, titled [Insets for hypertarget and hyperlinks](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.editors.lyx.devel/143518/focus=143523), discusses the question of interest.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the OPs question, which is about the `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` commands of `hyperref`. They allow you to add a link to any place in the document, and create a link to that location using any text as the link. With labels and cross references you're limited to numbered stuff as your targets, and whatever you can get from the cross reference commands as link text.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I think it actually answers the OPs real question, which is: how can I... _...click on to move to another part of the document_. Best,

Comment: Hmmm... ok, give me a sec to re-review!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I guess you are right. It does not answer completely -- though, the OP asked _Is there any other way to make text links without hyperlink/hypertarget...?_ So, I think it is a valid answer.

Comment: Well, we'll see when the OP checks back. Making any text into a link is not straightforward with labels and cross references though, unless I've missed something.

Comment: Same question (?) without an answer: http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg66105.html :-(

Comment: Even closer (?): http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.editors.lyx.devel/143518/focus=143523

Comment: Yep, that's it. Why don't you add a link to that discussion in your answer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8293/discussion-between-nikos-alexandris-and-torbjorn-t)